# C++ Make function unaccessable in the child class

Tags: c++11, inheritance

I have complex parent class which is being inherited. For now I need just to override a handful of its functions and would like to prevent somehow the possibility to call some non-overridden functions of the parent class in the child object (these functions from parent class would not work properly). I would define them later, if necessary, just want to make it clear, that for now they are not usable, **but still inherit some functions to make polymorphism possible**. Is it possible to achieve it? Or do I need to change the design?

Here is a small example:

```
class ParentClass
{
public:
    virtual void write() { ... }
    virtual void read() { ... }
    virtual void calculate() { ... }
};

class ChildClass : public ParentClass
{
public:
    void calculate() override { ... }
};
```

I would like to prevent the possibility to call `read` or `write` functions from the `ChildClass` object, because these functions are complex to define and I don't need them right now. But at the same time I would like to prevent someone from using parent inherited functions in `ChildClass`. What is important, `Parent class` is defined in the 3rd party library and I cannot change the parent class.

My (clumsy) idea was to override these functions and throw in them to make it obvious, that they are not accessible, but it is so far from proper design... What could be the proper solution?

Comment: Lack virtual keyword in subclass.

Comment: Actually virtual is not needed as long as I use override specifier

Comment: You should mark them `protected` instead of `public`. Then they can only be called in implementation of child class, but not from someone using an instance of the child class.

Comment: What if I am using a library and cannot change the parent class? I will add this to the question description.

Comment: You could use non-public inheritance from parent class, e.g. you could do `class ChildClass : private ParentClass`. This makes it so that users of `ChildClass` cannot "see" that it derives from parent class. E.g. they won't be able to call public functions from `ParentClass`, and they won't be able to pass a `ChildClass` to a function that takes `ParentClass &`.

Comment: Thanks Chris! But still, I want to inherit part of the functions and make the polymorphism possible, just prevent the use of part of the functions, like read and write here. I am not sure if it is doable...

Comment: @jendker I think what I would do is use private inheritance and then explicitly forward the functions that I want to be public.

Comment: Thanks Chris, that's what I will do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach when e.g. you want to use part of a class to implement a new class, and you want to use inheritance, but you don't want to expose the whole API of the base class, is to use private inheritance, and then pick and choose what you want to forward.

Here's an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class ParentClass
{
public:
    virtual void write() { printf("write"); }
    virtual void read() { printf("read"); }
    virtual void calculate() { printf("calculate"); }
    virtual void other() { printf("other"); }

};

class ChildClass : private ParentClass
{
public:
    void calculate() override { printf("new calculate"); }
    using ParentClass::other;
};

int main() {
    ChildClass c;
    c.calculate();
    c.other();
}
```

In godbolt compiler explorer I get this generated assembly (as expected)

```
.LC0:
  .string "new calculate"
.LC1:
  .string "other"
main:
  sub rsp, 8
  mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
  xor eax, eax
  call printf
  mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
  xor eax, eax
  call printf
  xor eax, eax
  add rsp, 8
  ret
```

The `using ParentClass::other` syntax (for forwarding a function from the base class without changes) is C++11 only, you didn't tag the function c++11 so I don't know if you can use that :), but it is handy

Comment: Added C++11 flag :) Thanks! It's a shame, that it is not possible to define it somehow the other way around, to specify which functions are not used, but it is pretty unusual case and I guess I will have to live with that

Answer (score -2):

Never had to code something like that and I can't at the moment try this solution out, so take this with a grain of salt.

I think you can declare them as `deleted` in the child class while keeping them virtual in the base class. This should prompt a compile time error when you try to use it on an object from a child class. That is, in the child class:

```
void write = deleted;
void read = deleted;
```

Unfortunately, I'm not 100% sure this would work on a virtual function. If not, you can also try to remove the `virtual` keyword from those functions in the parent class and use plain overload in the child class with deleted functions as above or even simply declare them without defining them (I prefer deleted functions as they are more explicit). Again, this should prompt a compile time error. You would of course lose the advantage of polymorphism, though.

Let me know if these solutions work.

Comment: Thanks Andrea! I tried this out and I am getting error: deleted function 'write' cannot override non-deleted function